# What "Unprotect" actually does?

Tags: support, protected-questions

Having loads of reputation, I saw a link "Unprotect" below one question which is currently protected.
[image: Unprotect]

The hover text says:

> allow answers by anonymous and very new low rep users

Well, duh. So far so good. But, **Is single unprotect vote enough to unprotect the question?**

I do not want to try that out for obvious reasons, thats why I am asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protecting and unprotecting a question can be done **unilaterally by anyone with the [protect questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege.**

I even think that anyone with that privilege can unprotect a question that was protected by a diamond moderator.

Protecting the question simply causes any user who wants to answer it to need at least 10 reputation that has been earned on the site (that is, beyond the association bonus if any). Users with less reputation earned on the site won't see the answer box for that particular question, and will see an explanationary note instead. All other things that can be done to the question and the answers on it are unaffected; this is unlike [locked questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) (a diamond moderator only privilege) which cannot be changed at all.